# Formularios dinámicos con componentes dinámicos vs solo formularios dinámicos - Angular forms

Tags: formularios, angular4

Tengo una consulta,
necesito lidear con los formularios dinámicos, a un 100% mi deseo es hacer todo tipo de campos dinamicos(botones submit, input, number, select, datepicker, fileInput).

Tengo dos ejemplos de muestras.
Uno el que muestra la misma pagina de Angular, con solo formularios dinamicos:
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form
El otro donde muestra Formularios dinámicos con componentes dinámicos: 
Ejm. https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-dynamic-forms

Me gustaría saber si es ventajoso utilizar formularios dianamicos con los componentes dinamicos, con la directiva así como el segundo ejemplo. o solo como el primero que solo se centra en el formulario dinamico.
Gracias..

Answer (score 2):

Es una pregunta **sin respuesta 100% segura**, al no tener la noción de en que contexto se va a utilizar o cual es tu proyecto. Es una característica referente al diseño del mismo, tal vez.

**Basándome en experiencias personales**, siempre realice formularios dinámicos y cubrió todas mis expectativas.
Si tuviera que diferenciar entre *formularios dinámicos con los componentes dinámicos* y *solo formularios dinámicos*, te diría que:

> Lo primero (*formularios dinámicos con los componentes dinámicos*) es
>   muchísimo mas re utilizable, a la vez que te puede llevar mas tiempo
>   hacerlo, podrás usarlo en mas proyectos futuros. A la vez, que si tu proyecto se basa en gran cantidad de formularios, esto te sera muy útil al permitirte una gran granularidad en los componentes de los formularios, con todas las ventajas que esto conlleva.

Por otro lado:

> Los formularios dinámicos, tienen las ventajas que ya se conocen
>   (referentes a un formulario dinamico) y un menor grado de
>   reutilizacion comparado con los anteriores y puede tener un grado de dificultad menor para realizarlos, seria mas recomendable para proyectos chicos referente a formularios.

---

**Como conclusión:**

Utiliza formularios dinámicos con los componentes dinámicos, si tienes el tiempo suficiente en tu proyecto y es el "core" del mismo, ya que te va a permitir mucha flexibilidad, tanto como mantenibilidad y reusabilidad, aprovechando la lógica de diseño a la que apunta Angular, la cual es realizar componentes tan atómicos como tu proyecto lo requiera. Teniendo en cuenta tu necesidad de *"lidear con los formularios dinamicos, a un 100%"*, te recomendaría hacer uso de componentes dinámicos, ten presente que es una recomendación basada en mi experiencia personal y puede variar dependiendo de tus restricciones y contexto del proyecto.